# IllegalStateExecption Android studio Webview App

Tags: android, illegalstateexception, java, android-binder

I am currently trying to run my app on a AVD and keep getting this error. When i export it and install it on a tablet at work (unsure of API) but i cant get it to work on the AVD and on an old galaxy note 2.
This is the error i get from the android monitor. And the galaxy note 2 just says Unfortunatley, Package installer has failed.

```
Error: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ☃Requested internal only, but not 
enough space


$ adb shell pm uninstall australia.defence.cubic.lisportal
Unknown failure (at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:565))
Error while Installing APK
```

Any help would be great. If you need more info let me know. It is a simple webview app with javascript and domstorage enabled.

```
    private native final void destroy();

    private static final void sendDeathNotice(DeathRecipient recipient) {
        if (false) Log.v("JavaBinder", "sendDeathNotice to " + recipient);
        try {
            recipient.binderDied();
        }
        catch (RuntimeException exc) {
            Log.w("BinderNative", "Uncaught exception from death notification",
                    exc);
        }
    }
[this is the location of the Binder.java:565]
    final private WeakReference mSelf;
    private long mObject;
    private long mOrgue;
}
```

Cheers

Comment: Your device seems to be full ("not enough space").

Comment: Ok, but i have 20gb left on my galaxy note 2, so that shouldnt be an issue

Comment: Anything else it could be. The apk is 500mb (lots of images converted from pdfs)

Comment: I am not aware of many distribution channels that support a 500MB APK, so you may have bigger problems. Try removing the images, and see if the APK installs. If it does, your APK is too big.

Comment: yep, solved the AVD dont know about the galaxy note though. Kind of need the files. What is the max size and how else can i avoid this (store files on device storage instead)?

Comment: "What is the max size" -- that depends in part on your distribution channel. Play Store is 50MB or 100MB, I forget which. "how else can i avoid this (store files on device storage instead)" -- download the images from a server to `getCacheDir()` or something.

Comment: ok so error still occurs on galaxy note 2, although the AVD is working. I assume this is a different issue then (API?). I dont need this to go on a store. This will be an app for a customer on tablets that will never touch the internet for security. I am assuming if i can figure out the real error for the galaxy note 2, the size shouldnt be an issue (works on another tablet)

Comment: "I assume this is a different issue then (API?)" -- usually, the error would indicate if you have a `minSdkVersion` issue. "This will be an app for a customer on tablets that will never touch the internet for security" -- then, why are you worried about a Galaxy Note 2?

Comment: try 'adb shell pm setInstallLocation 2' which will force to install the app on external storage

Comment: I'm trying it on multiple devices, because they may want it on different devices, but my point is it will be controlled by me.

Comment: Niphin- it doesn't have an sd card in it, only the internal storage. Would having a permission for write to external clash with the fact I have no external? Wouldn't think so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok so I figured out once I got developer mode working on my note, apparently the issue was file size, but not the app, the icons I made for it. So I reduced them down from some stupid size to a more reasonable and it works.